# Add to a players total score

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When a player scores, I want to add +1 to the players total score (totPoints).
Unfortunately, my present code:

```
  const [number, setNumber] = useState('');
  const [totPoints, setTotPoints] = useState(0);
  const [scorers, setScorers] = useState([]);

  const sortedScorers = [...scorers].sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number);
  const onePointScoredHandler = () => {
    const players = [...scorers];

    const pos = players.map((player) => player.number).indexOf(+number);

    if (pos !== -1) {
      console.log('exist');
      players[pos].totPoints = setTotPoints(totPoints + 1);
      setScorers(players);
    } else {
      console.log('new');
      const newScorer = {
        id: nanoid(4),
        number: +number,
        totPoints: totPoints + 1,
      };
      setScorers([...scorers, newScorer]);
      setTotPoints(totPoints);
    }
    setNumber('');
    console.log(scorers);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h4>Individual points</h4>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="number"
        value={number}
        onChange={(e) => setNumber(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={onePointScoredHandler}>Add 1p</button>
      <br />
      <br />
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NUMBER</th>
            <th>Total Points</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {sortedScorers
            .sort((a, b) => a.number - b.number)
            .map((player) => (
              <tr key={player.id}>
                <td>{player.id}</td>
                <td>{player.number}</td>
                <td>{player.totPoints}</td>
              </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
```

don't works as intended:

1. When the player scores first time, it's working, i.e totPoints = 1
2. if that player scores again i get `totPoints: undefined`
3. If now a new player scores, the `totPoints = 2` and not`totPoints = 1` as it should be

I hope you can rescue me even this time....
Thanks in advance

Regards
Peter

PS: I´ve tried with
`players[pos].totPoints = setTotPoints((prevState) => prevState + 1)`
with the same disappointing results...

Comment: how to add a new player ? . I can't add more than 1 player because when i click on the button after the first time . It keeps getting into the `exist` .

Comment: I enter a number i input field, and click the button

Comment: @Shyam: maybe because you have to enter a number in input before you click? Can´t leave the field empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You are mutating the state object.

```
players[pos].totPoints = setTotPoints(totPoints + 1); // mutation!!
setScorers(players);
```

Even though you copied the array with `const players = [...scorers];` the elements in the array still reference the elements of the old array.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to match a previous scorer to increment their `totPoints` value. Remember, when updated React state you *must* shallow copy *any* state that is being updated, included nested state.

```
setScorers((scorers) =>
  scorers.map((scorer, index) =>
    index === pos
      ? {
          ...scorer,
          totPoints: scorer.totPoints + 1
        }
      : scorer
  )
);
```

[image: Edit add-to-a-players-total-score]

Comment: Thanks @Drew Reese:-)
Do you mean that I do not need / should not use ```indexOf()```  but should use your solution?

Comment: It's not like you should not use `indexOf`, but the point to be considered here is **one should not mutate the state directly**.

Comment: Thanks both! Now I understand it. I´m old and slow in mind...